# Reading each line form a text file and determining if it has another letter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file that looks like this:

A  12 YDUSD ASSDAS  FSDDSFSD SDFF

AA FSDFSD FSDF SDFSDG GSDDSFS SDF

AB SDFSDF SDFFSDFDS SDSDSDSDS

ACC SDFSDDSDFSD EW12 SDFSD 3322

ACDD FDSDSFS SDFGSDG DSGSDF

AB FSDFSD SDF34 223DSFSD

ABBD 2332 ADSDFDSFDS

And so on and so fourth for about 500 different beginnings to each line. I want to write a program that will get the line, take everything from it before the first tab (there is a tab between each column) and put it into a list like this:

['A', 'AA', 'AB', 'ACC', 'ACDD', 'AB', 'ABBD']

This is my program so far but it doesn't quite work:

```
file1 = open("filename", "r")
file2 = open("filename2", "w")
i=0
k = 0
sp500list = []
with open("filename1") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
while (abc < len(lines)):
    LineStr = str(lines[i])
    j = 0
    if (LineStr[j] != ''):     
        j = j + 1        
        if (LineStr[j] !=''):             
            j = j + 1
        elif (LineStr[j] == ' '):
            sp500list.append(str(LineStr[:2]))
            i = i + 1
            if (LineStr[j] !=''):
                j = j + 1
            elif (LineStr[j] == ' '):
                sp500list.append(str(LineStr[:3]))
                i = i + 1
                if (LineStr[j] !=''):
                    sp500list.append(str(LineStr[:4]))                    
                    i = i + 1
                    j = 0        

    elif (LineStr[j] == ' '):
        i = i + 1        
    print sp500list     
    abc = abc + 1
```

So far all it does is return an empty array, can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you testing for characters equal to a space, if the separator is a tab? Split the line on tab `"\t"` and take the first element... `sp500list = [line.split("\t")[0] for line in open("C:\Users\Tom Pitts\Desktop\Katrina\sp500tick.txt")]` might well do it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified. `split` each line by `'\t'`, and take the first element of the resulting list.

```
>>> with open('file.txt') as f:
...     result = [line.split('\t', 1)[0] for line in f]
... 
>>> result
['A', 'AA', 'AB', 'ACC', 'ACDD', 'AB', 'ABBD']
```

Alternatively, use `result = [line[:line.find('\t')] for line in f]`.